# Missing gems when run bundle exec by sudo -u git -H

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, gitlab

I installed `Gitlab` on my server,

Created a `git` by `sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git`

So the tutorial told me I should run ``

I used another user account to run those commands,

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

But it raised those errors

```
Could not find rake-10.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Instead of those commands, I did `su git` to `git`, then run those commands without  `sudo -u git -H` in the begin of commands.

Comment: What did the tutorial tell you to run? The command is missing in your question.

Comment: Does https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5279#issuecomment-32146387 help?